# Sticky Footer does overlaps text on pages requiring scrolling

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, sticky-footer

I have a sticky footer with the following CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">

.HeaderTBL
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    min-width:960px;
    max-width:100%;
    background-color: #333333; 
}

.FooterTBL
{
    width: 100%;
    min-width:960px;
    max-width:100%;
    position:inherit;
    bottom:0;
}

.Footer
{
    position:absolute;
    height: 25px;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%; 
}

</style>
```

and my code is as follows:

```
<body style="margin: 0;">
<form id="form1" runat="server">            
<asp:ScriptManager ID="MasterSM" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
      <table class="HeaderTBL">
                <tr>
                    <td width="75%">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="25%" align="right">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="SearchTB" runat="server" 
                            ToolTip="Search" 
                            Width="216px" Height="25px" ForeColor="#333333" BorderColor="White" 
                                BorderStyle="None" Font-Names="Candara" Font-Overline="False" 
                                Font-Size="Medium"></asp:TextBox>

                            <asp:RoundedCornersExtender ID="SearchTBRCE" runat="server" Enabled="True" 
                                TargetControlID="SearchTB" BorderColor="White">
                                </asp:RoundedCornersExtender>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table align="center" width="960px" style="min-height:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td width="150px" align="center" valign="top">
            <asp:Image ID="LogoIMG" runat="server" Height="150px" ImageAlign="Left" 
                ImageUrl="~/Images/Logo.gif" Width="150px" />
        </td>
        <td width="810px" rowspan="2" align="center" valign="top">
                   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Body" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="150px" align="center" valign="top">
            <asp:Label ID="LoginLBL" runat="server" Text="Login"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
        </table>

<div class="Footer">
    <table class="FooterTBL" style="bottom: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" 

            style="font-family: Candara; font-size: medium; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: medium; border-top-color: #333333; color: #333333;">
                Test Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

But for some reason, when on my content page (this is my master page) I have text longer than the height of the page, the footer stays in its position and does not move underneath the body of the text.

Can anyone give me a heads up as to whats happening and any way to fix?

Comment: It is bad practice to use tables in a footer. Tables should be used for data presentation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning. I just felt it gives me a little bit more control over my layout...

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` to tell the footer to always be at the bottom of your screen, no matter what. If you want to have it flow after the content, `set position: relative`

Comment: By doing this, the footer just rises straight back to the bottom of my content...

Comment: You need to give as a link to work with, can you upload your site somewhere?

Comment: Also, the footer doesn't always stay at the bottom. If I scroll the page, the footer will scroll likewise...

Comment: I only have two pages atm: the content page and the master view page, and I don't have any web server to upload it to... I could possibly upload my files to a file-hosting site, but which one I wouldn't know